# jQuery Hide Show when multiple selectors

Tags: javascript, jquery, show-hide

I am trying to toggle hide/show on multiple elements, and it works on mobile, however on desktop, my code seems to hide/show all of them instead of the parent that is being clicked on.

```
var t = $(this).find*
$('div a i').click(function(){
    $('.text').toggleClass('show');     
});
```

Here is a [CodePen](http://www.bootply.com/nQAdbBrPow) with my markup.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Not sure `.find*` is valid. I think you aimed `.find('*')`

Comment: Adjusted to var t = $(this).find('*'); but it didn't make any difference.

Comment: you dont use t anywehre, ant its outside of click...

Comment: Indeed... the `t` variable is useless and not used :) When I click on one marker, all the text labels hide and show, which is what your code seems to be doing. Isn't that the correct behaviour?

Comment: I thought I was using it, but I was in a previous version of the script I was writing. Just to help ease my mind on too much code. Thank you for pointing that out.

Comment: Jeremy, that wasn't what was supposed to happen. What was, was one item shows while the rest remains hidden.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

did you try this?

Edit to your comment:

```
$('div.pop-up').click(function(){
    $('.text').removeClass('show');
    $(this).find('.text').toggleClass('show');      
});
```

You have to say which div to click by class, otherwise, partent div's are clicked as will...

Comment: How would I go about hiding the other elements? I tried something like
   $('div').click(function () {
        $('text').removeClass('show');
        $(this).find('.text').toggleClass('show');
    });

But that didn't work to toggle.

Comment: Thank you so much! I am still doing what I can to learn jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

It's for the a:hoover

```
html > body a:hover + .text { display: block; }
```

If you trigger the div,the text don't disappear